# list in def function

Tags: python, list, function

I have been trying to solve this problem in def function for doing a list and return it but it seems have to use your help.

```
def something():
    a_list = []
    a_list.append("note")
    return a_list
def main():
    b_list = []
    c = something()
    b_list.append(c)
    print(b_list)
main()
```

Output:

```
['note'] #normally will print note only
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try using `.extend` instead of `.append`:

```py
b_list.extend(c)
```